# sqlalchemy: assert dispatch_reg[owner_ref] == listen_ref

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Invenio 2.0 and try to replace old version of SQLAlchemy 0.8.7 with the last 0.9.7.
The utility to automaticaly create the db works (inveniomanage database recreate --yes-i-know).

But when I start tests with: python setup.py test

It return me a error:

```
test_fisrt_blueprint (invenio.testsuite.test_ext_template.TemplateLoaderCase) ... --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR in wrappers [/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/src/invenio/invenio/ext/logging/wrappers.py:310]:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/src/invenio/invenio/ext/legacy/__init__.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.app.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1470, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1497, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
    func()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/src/invenio/invenio/modules/messages/views.py", line 264, in invoke_email_alert_register
    email_alert_register()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/src/invenio/invenio/modules/messages/models.py", line 202, in email_alert_register
    event.listen(MsgMESSAGE, 'after_insert', email_alert)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/api.py", line 63, in listen
    _event_key(target, identifier, fn).listen(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/registry.py", line 187, in listen
    self.dispatch_target.dispatch._listen(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/events.py", line 547, in _listen
    event_key.base_listen(**kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/registry.py", line 226, in base_listen
    for_modify(target.dispatch).append(self, propagate)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 328, in append
    event_key.append_to_list(self, self.listeners)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/registry.py", line 237, in append_to_list
    _stored_in_collection(self, owner)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/registry.py", line 74, in _stored_in_collection
    assert dispatch_reg[owner_ref] == listen_ref
AssertionError
```

In /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/src/invenio/invenio/modules/messages/views.py (row 264)

```
# Registration of email_alert invoked from blueprint
# in order to use before_app_first_request.
# Reading config CFG_WEBMESSAGE_EMAIL_ALERT
# required app context.
@blueprint.before_app_first_request
def invoke_email_alert_register():
    email_alert_register()
```

In /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/invenio2/src/invenio/invenio/modules/messages/models.py (row 202)

```
# Registration of email_alert invoked from blueprint
# in order to use before_app_first_request.
# Reading config CFG_WEBMESSAGE_EMAIL_ALERT
# required app context.
def email_alert_register():
    if cfg['CFG_WEBMESSAGE_EMAIL_ALERT']:
        from sqlalchemy import event
        # Register after insert callback.
        event.listen(MsgMESSAGE, 'after_insert', email_alert)
```

Someone can help me?

Installed:

```
-e git+https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy@c7eccba63314f3ea77e2c6217d3d3c8b0d2552fd#egg=Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.0
MySQL-python==1.2.5
SQLAlchemy==0.9.7
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.23.5
```

Answer (score 1):

With help from google (today) I found what I suspect would be a solution here (I'm not an invenio user)

I suspect an SQLa update will fix your issue.

https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3199/deduplication-of-events-doesnt-work-for

-->

https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/commits/9ae4db27b993

-->

Fixed in SQLA 0.9.8 (supposedly)